# Ember computed properly not firing on property change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having a weird issue where a computed property isn't firing when it's dependent properties change.

*Computed Property and Actions*

```
answers: computed('variant.questionAnswers.[]', function() {
  return get(this, 'variant.questionAnswers').sortBy('position');
}),

...

actions: {
  reorderItems(answerModels) {
    answerModels.forEach(function(item, index) {
      set(item, 'position', index + 1);
    });
  }
}
```

The `answerModels` in the action is an array of all the answers, and setting the position works properly in that action. I can see the position changing in the ember inspector as well as when I inspect the individual models.

However, it does not update the view order because the `answers` computed property does not get fired.

I've tried changing the dependent property to `variant.questionAnswers`, `variant.questionAnswers.@each.position`, `variant.questionAnswers.[]`, but nothing seem to fire when I change the position in the action.

How I got around it was add a `timeHack` attribute that makes it work, but obviously is not ideal...

```
timeHack: null,

answers: computed('timeHack', 'variant.questionAnswers.[]', function() {
  return get(this, 'variant.questionAnswers').sortBy('position');
}),

actions: {
  reorderItems(answerModels) {
    answerModels.forEach(function(item, index) {
      set(item, 'position', index + 1);
    });
    set(this, 'timeHack', new Date());
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

`variant.questionAnswers.@each.position` is the correct dependent key for the computed property you have created.  The reason i say that is because `position` is the actual value that you are changing in each array item.. so it is not sufficient to observe the array items alone.

the part that is not clear to me.. in your question: is `answerModels` array in the action, in fact, the same `variant.questionAnswers` array you are comparing in the computed property?

When i look closer at your action.. it does not look like your code would do anything to change the overall sort order?  you are increasing all the items position by `+1`, so maybe that is why you dont visually see a change in the sort order.

Comment: `variant.questionAnswers.@each.position` did not work for me. When putting a debugger in the computed property, it does not fire. The `answerModels` come into the action in the newly sorted order. So I'm just looping through them and setting their position attributes based on their new order.

Comment: if `answerModels` is not the same array as `varient.questionAnswers` that is the reason your computed property is not firing.

Comment: But I'm changing the actual models. That means any computed properties observing those models should also fire.